# Lost intellisense and syntax highlighting in visual studio javascript files

Tags: visual-studio-2015, syntax-highlighting, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

I recently had to transition to a new laptop and somehow my new installation of visual studio has no intellisense or syntax highlighting for js files (other files like xml, html, c#, etc have this working fine). I tried using the search in tools -> options for javascript in the search bar and no options came up. I also tried right clicking my .js file -> "open with" and did not see any options for a javascript editor. It was defaulted to "JSON Editor".

Anyone know how to get this enabled again? This is slowing down my development a bit.

Comment: Did you search? There are a bunch of topics here with different solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue if you have **Universal Windows App Development Tools** installed.

To fix this

**A - Get the SP updated on your Visual Studio 2015**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt622450.aspx

**B - If the update doesn't work there's a work around**

- If the “Universal Windows App Development Tools” are still installed:

  1. Go to Programs and Features, select Visual Studio 2105, click
     Change.
  2. In Visual Studio setup, click Modify.
  3. Deselect the feature Universal Windows App Development Tools
  4. Select “Universal Windows App Development Tools” again, and click Update.
- If you have already uninstalled the Universal Windows App Development Tools:

  1. Reinstall “Universal Windows App Development Tools”
  2. Or, take the following steps to reinstall the JavaScript project system and language service:

     - Download the installer for your edition of Visual Studio, e.g. vs_community.exe.
     - Open a CMD window, and run the following command: vs_community.exe /modify /installselectableitems JavaScript_Hidden /passive